# I haven't been able to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 or because of apt-get release problems. Now I am told that 19.10 is no longer supported

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

```
unable to download updates:failed to refresh cache
could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. it is held in process 5578 (apt-get)-open(11:resource temporarily unavailable)
```

This is typical response, process number will change when trying another time.

Comment: First fix the lock problem by following the link in the other comment. Then follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, 19.10 is a short support release. Support ended somewhere in July, and indeed, it is not supported (and may not be possible) to upgrade from an unsupported release. At this point, you should perform a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. Keep in mind that you need to upgrade short time releases shortly after a new release is available.

Ubuntu 20.04 happens to be a long term release. It will therefore be supported for five years. During that time, you will be able to upgrade during the entire life time of the next short support release (20.10) or, over two years, upgrade to the next long support release, 22.04.